# Как добавить неограниченное количество кнопок в telegram bot?

Tags: python, list, telegram, бот, for

Как добавить неограниченное количество кнопок в telegram bot по запросу пользователя?
Алгоритм такой:

- Пользователь пишет сообщение со значениями через запятую
- Создаётся список из этих значений и замена запятых
- Для каждого значения нужно создать отдельную кнопку

На этапе создания отдельной кнопки я завис. Данный пример на скрине выводит только одну кнопку - последний элемент в списке. Как я понял это из-за того что "фор" проходит по всему списку и когда выполняется вызов кнопок то значение в i уже последнее в заданном списке.
Как правильно настроить "фор"?

[image: lst - список в котором каждый элемент - отдельная кнопка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: создать клавиатуру сначала и в вашем цикле добавлять кнопки